# расстановка тире

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?
А попасть в его комнату было не так просто. На двери имелся замок — страшная редкость — и он запирал ее на ключ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что это не приложение, а **вставная конструкция**, выражающая попутное замечание, поэтому наличие двух тире обязательно. Тогда получаются такие варианты:

На двери имелся замок — страшная редкость, — и он запирал ее на ключ.

На двери имелся замок — страшная редкость! —  и он запирал ее на ключ.

На двери имелся замок (страшная редкость!), и он запирал ее на ключ.

**Пояснение**

Сочетание "страшная редкость" не может являться определением для "замка",  а приложение — это именно определение, выраженное существительным.

Поэтому нежелателен  вариант оформления с одним тире: На двери имелся замок — страшная редкость, и он запирал ее на ключ. Это встроенная конструкция, которая произносится без паузы, а в  нашем случае выделение паузами **оценочной реплики** явно присутствует.

—

Answer (score 3):

Это приложение  с пояснительным значением, поэтому возможно выделить двумя запятыми или двумя тире, но перед вторым тире тогда нужна ещё и запятая (отделить одно предложение от другого).

А лучше поставить воскл. знак, тогда запятой не будет, а эмоции будут переданы верно:На двери имелся замок - страшная редкость!- и он запирал ее на ключ.

Можно с одним тире:

На двери имелся замок — страшная редкость, и он запирал ее на ключ.

Можно так: На двери имелся замок ( страшная редкость!), и он запирал ее на ключ.